# Как смонтировать папку в linux из корневого пути?

Tags: linux, mount

Есть корневой каталог

```
/
```

где имеется 60Gb места.

Нужно смонтировать каталог

```
/data
```

из него, объемом 30Gb.

Как это правильно сделать чтобы после перезагрузки каталог не пропадал?
То есть чтобы после перезагрузки можно было зайти в каталог через cd?

Чтобы работало в centos, redos, ubuntu?

```
cd /data
```

Comment: А чем не устраивает просто сделать ссылку на этот каталог? Зачем именно монтировать?

Comment: Что-то ничего не понятно. Вы хотите сделать подкаталог с ограниченным размером в пределах одной файловой системы?

Comment: добавьте в /etc/fstab строку `/data    /куда_монтировать    none defaults,bind 0 0`

Comment: @PavelGridin но это не ограничит объём

Comment: @andreymal, на счёт размера и правда не понятно

Comment: Я смотрю как на другом сервере было сделано. Там как раз выделен отдельный каталог объемом 30. Поэтому думаю так же сделать, чтобы потом проблем не было. Хотя наверное не важно будет ли папка смонтирована или просто в корневом находится.

Comment: @manking, так это же наверное другой раздел размером 30 гб смонтирован на /data?

Comment: @PavelGridin
Ну наверное да, но он же был создан из корневого? То есть у корневого было 60, станет 30 и у /data тоже будет 30. 

А получается другой вариант есть ограничить /data максимальным объемом 30? Без монтирования?

Comment: «он же был создан из корневого?» — эта фраза не имеет смысла. То, что вы описываете — это уменьшить один раздел и в освободившемся месте создать другой раздел, но никакой связи разделов друг с другом в таком случае не будет. Про редактирование разделов в линуксе есть куча информации в интернете, а чтобы новый раздел автоматически монтировался при загрузке системы, нужно добавить запись в fstab (про который опять же куча информации в интернете)